# Why does a user require certain reputation points for writing comments?

Tags: discussion, comments

When new users comes along, they are not able to post comments on questions and answers due to lack of reputation points at the time. So they write replies and queries as answers on question when they should actually have been a comment on the question or an existing answer. The moderators then have to flag such answers and add those queries and replies as comments where applicable.

Instead of this why not allow user to comment right away without any pre-requisite of a certain reputation points?

Answer (score 4):

One of the main reasons is to prevent users from spamming in the comments. We want users to be invested in the site prior to commenting and in order to do this we want them to contribute positively and gain reputation.

### Related:

- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: But because of this there's some many new users who want to comment but can't and have to write the comment as an answer and moderators have to take care of moving them and removing them.

Comment: @TESTasy Yes that is an unfortunate side effect but users who spam the comments can be a bigger problem and those are much harder to detect.